# sharedpreferences android memory vmHeap

Tags: android, garbage-collection, sharedpreferences

I have an activity Settings where I set a value for a key in sharedPreferences.
If I set this key for 2-3-4 times the App crash.

`03-19 12:07:00.701 12542-12542/giordano.piercarmine.crossfitpersonalrecords I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 6% free, 54MB/58MB, paused 10ms total 20ms
03-19 12:07:00.701 12542-12542/giordano.piercarmine.crossfitpersonalrecords I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 10MB allocation
03-19 12:07:00.701 12542-12542/giordano.piercarmine.crossfitpersonalrecords I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
03-19 12:07:00.711 12542-12542/giordano.piercarmine.crossfitpersonalrecords I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 6% free, 54MB/58MB, paused 0 total 10ms
03-19 12:07:00.711 12542-12542/giordano.piercarmine.crossfitpersonalrecords W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 10840012 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 9MB until OOM"
03-19 12:07:00.721 12542-12542/giordano.piercarmine.crossfitpersonalrecords D/skia: --- decoder->decode returned false
03-19 12:07:00.721 12542-12542/giordano.piercarmine.crossfitpersonalrecords D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-19 12:07:00.721 12542-12542/giordano.piercarmine.crossfitpersonalrecords E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                              Process: giordano.piercarmine.crossfitpersonalrecords, PID: 12542
                                                                                              java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 10840012 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 9MB until OOM`

This is my Class for SharedPreferences:

`
    public class SessionManager {
    // LogCat tag
    //private static String TAG = SessionManager.class.getSimpleName();

```
// Shared Preferences
SharedPreferences pref;

Editor editor;
Context _context;

// Shared pref mode
int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

// Shared preferences file name
private static final String PREF_NAME = "AndroidHiveLogin";

private static final String KEY_IS_LOGGEDIN = "isLoggedIn";

private static final String TYPE_OF_WEIGHT = "Kg";

public SessionManager(Context context) {
    this._context = context;
    pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();
}

public void setLogin(boolean isLoggedIn) {

    editor.putBoolean(KEY_IS_LOGGEDIN, isLoggedIn);

    // commit changes
    editor.commit();

    //Log.d(TAG, "User login session modified!");
}

public boolean isLoggedIn(){
    return pref.getBoolean(KEY_IS_LOGGEDIN, false);
}

public void setTypeOfWeight(String typeOfWeight){
    editor.putString(TYPE_OF_WEIGHT, typeOfWeight);
    editor.apply();

}

public String getTypeOfWeight(){
    return pref.getString(TYPE_OF_WEIGHT, "Kg");
}
```

`
In all activity I create a instace of this class with new. Is this the right way?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are saving a value of about 10 mega bytes.
SharedPreferences is not used for storing data. It is designed to store small, key value pairs such as settings , user names , ids , options etc.

You may use SQLLite instead.

Comment: thanks man. I found the error. When i click save button in activity setting i switch to another activity (mainActivity) through intent and startActivity(intent). If i click multiple times on the button save i make multiple instance of this activity and the memory increase 10mb each time